# Java, Android - Handle comma in csv export

Tags: java, android, csv

I am exporting a table to a .csv file, but I have the usual problem with commas in the fields.

This is how I populate the .csv file:

```
outCSV.write(todoItemsID.get(a) + "," + todoItemsGROUP.get(a)  + "," + todoItemsNAME.get(a) + "," 
+ todoItemsFINISHED.get(a) + "," + todoItemsNOTES.get(a) + "," + todoItemsQUANTITY.get(a) + "\n");
```

What if there is a comma or a new line e.g. in the todoItemsNotes.get(a) field? How should I handle that?

Comment: if you still face issue http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10629/agarwal

Answer (score 0):

Use double-quotes to surround that string. It generally works for most tools that read CSV files.

```
outCSV.write(todoItemsID.get(a) + "," + todoItemsGROUP.get(a)  + "," + todoItemsNAME.get(a) + "," 
+ todoItemsFINISHED.get(a) + ",\"" + todoItemsNOTES.get(a) + "\"," + todoItemsQUANTITY.get(a) + "\n");
```

Comment: heads up, any double quotes in the quoted string must then be escaped.  don't re-invent the wheel, Bruce Dunwiddie maintains a tiny open-source class with plenty of csv utils here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/

Comment: Rajesh: thanks, I didn't how to use the double quotes.
Tom: I added the jar as a library to my project. What next?

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to use this library? I have a CsvReader.class and a CsvWriter.class, but no java files in this .jar.